# Specify key for many-to-many relationship in go-pg ORM

Tags: go, go-pg

I have these 2 models with many-to-many relationship:

```
type Person struct {
    tableName    struct{}   `sql:"person"`
    UUID         string     `sql:"person_uuid,pk"`
    ContactDatas []ContactData `pg:",many2many:person_contact_data,joinFK:"`
}

type ContactData struct {
    tableName     struct{}   `sql:"contact_data"`
    UUID          string     `sql:"contact_data_uuid,pk"`
}
```

And model for `person_contact_data` table is:

```
type PersonContactData struct {
    tableName       struct{} `sql:"person_contact_data"`
    PersonUUID      string   `sql:"person_uuid"`
    ContactDataUUID string   `sql:"contact_data_uuid"`
}
```

If `joinFK` in `ContactDatas` struct tag is empty go-pg adds underscore under the hood, so generated SQL part looks like this: `WHERE ("contact_data"."contact_data_uuid" = person_contact_data."_contact_data_uuid")`.

Is there a way to specify joining keys completely manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using version 5. In latest version this was fixed, now you can specify full joining keys:

```
type Person struct {
    tableName    struct{}   `sql:"person"`
    UUID         string     `sql:"person_uuid,pk"`
    ContactDatas []ContactData `pg:",many2many:person_contact_data,fk:person_uuid,joinFK:contact_data_uuid"`
}
```